# ARC clarification: Will my class extension properties be released automatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting

I'm new to ARC, and I have little question I didn't find info about.

I'm writing communication class and I want to add properties to a 3rd party class.
I wrote this code in my `communicationClass.h`:

```
@interface AFHTTPRequestOperation()

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TargetProtocol> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) SEL callback;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *requestIdentifier;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int authenticationMode;

@end
```

The properties are added fine and I use them. My question is,
will ARC release these properties even if `AFHTTPRequestOperation`
is extended in a different file (my `communicationClass.h`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding your additional properties using a class extension (not a category).  Class extensions can only be used when you have access to the original source code for the class being extended.  In this case you presumably have the source code for `AFNetworking` included in your project.

Apple's [Programming with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) has this to say about class extensions:

> A class extension bears some similarity to a category, but it can only
>   be added to a class for which you have the source code at compile time
>   (the class is compiled at the same time as the class extension). The
>   methods declared by a class extension are implemented in the
>   @implementation block for the original class so you can’t, for
>   example, declare a class extension on a framework class, such as a
>   Cocoa or Cocoa Touch class like NSString.

and

> Unlike regular categories, a class extension can add its own
>   properties and instance variables to a class. If you declare a
>   property in a class extension, [...] the compiler will automatically
>   synthesize the relevant accessor methods, as well as an instance
>   variable, inside the primary class implementation.

This would suggest that properties added by a class extension will function exactly the same as they would if they were in the original implementation file.  However, the documentation suggests that the class extension should be compiled at the same time as the original implementation, I'm not clear how this happens if the `communicationClass.h` is not included in the original `AFHTTPRequestOperation.m` implementation file.

Given that the properties are working for you I would have to assume that the Objective-C Runtime is recognising them and this likely means that ARC will work correctly.

It is probably worth testing this.  To check that ARC correctly releases the property I would add some logging to the `dealloc` method of a class that you are storing in a property added using this method.  If the `dealloc` gets called when the parent is destroyed then you'll know it is working.

Comment: Why do you say he's using a class extension when he states that he's adding properties to a 3rd party class?

Comment: @trojanfoe `@interface AFHTTPRequestOperation()` declares a class extension, not a category.  Plus categories don't allow adding properties, only methods.

Comment: The only reason this is working for the OP is because they are extending `AFNetworking` and they have the source code in the project.

Comment: But how do you *know* he has the source code?  He didn't say he did.

Comment: I don't *know* that he has the source but he is trying to extend `AFNetworking`, an open source project. Plus, according to the Apple documentation a class extension can only be used when it is compiled at the same time as the original class.

Comment: OK, that seems fair enough.

Comment: Forgot to say, i do have the source of AFNetworking, but would not like to change it so i can easily update the source in the future.
I choosed this approche because it simple and elegant, without the need to subclass and add unneeded files to the project. thanks for helping

Comment: @mttrb Class extensions definitely do allow property declarations, as well as method and ivar declarations.

Comment: @BJHomer Yep, did I say otherwise?

Comment: @mttrb: oh, I misread; you were talking about categories there, not class extensions. Sorry. (Though technically you *can* declare properties in a category; you just can't synthesize them.)

Comment: Yeah, it could be done in a category with `objc_setAssociatedObject` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, if the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` class is compiled with ARC support. When the answer ist **yes**, than the ARC will handle this. Otherwise, it will not and the answer is **no**.

Another thing is that `retain` should be `strong` when using ARC.

Comment: Another question would be "is that an answer or a comment?"

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** your extension will be dealt by ARC.

You are not required to worry about it.

And it would look good if you use `weak` and `strong` in `@property`

Answer (score 0):

I would say "Yes", they will be managed for you, and this based on this [blog article](http://www.techpaa.com/2012/04/adding-properties-to-categories-and.html) that talks about how properties are managed in categories using `objc_setAssociatedObject()`.  At the end of the article the author states:

> Note: When class object(UIView object) is deallocated, its property
>   (animationIdentifer) will be sent a -release message automatically.

So I am *assuming* that ARC would do this for you.  It's not very authoritative, I know...